# What's this linchpin on hydraulic brakes

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, sram

I just got a new bike with SRAM Level Hydraulic disc brakes. After riding it home, I noticed both the front and rear brakes have a silver linchpin holding something in place. It almost looks like it's holding the pads in place, but also kinda looks like it's supposed to be removed.

[image]

Can someone tell me what this pin is doing, and was I supposed to remove it before riding the bike? If I'm not supposed to remove it, in what maintenance scenario would I ever remove it? If I was supposed to remove it, is it possible I've done damage by riding with it in place?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a standard "cotter pin".  You can find replacements in any reasonably well-stocked hardware store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cotter pin holds the pads in the correct position. It would only be removed to replace the pads when worn. For information sake the silver color plates are springs that help retract the pads away from the rotor when the brakes are released. They also prevent brake squeal by limiting vibration.

Comment: Thanks! After looking at it a bit closer, I kind of gathered all this, except the brake squeal part. On first look, it just looked out of place since it's the only obvious silver finished part, everything else being black.